# Update Query From 2 Table

Tags: sql, nested

I have the below 2 tables:

table1 is `tracsName,tracsid,N,NE...` table2 is `Tracs,kode,N2...`. I want to change N value with N2 value with this code, the N and more is the wind arrow

Update query, can more simple?
`UPDATE table1
SET
    N=(select N2 from table2 where tracs='daraname2' AND kode='1-6'),
    NE=(select NE2 from table2 where tracs='daraname2' AND kode='1-6'),
    E=(select E2 from table2 where tracs='daraname2' AND kode='1-6'),
    SE=(select SE2 from table2 where tracs='daraname2' AND kode='1-6'),
    S=(select S2 from table2 where tracs='daraname2' AND kode='1-6'),
    SW=(select SW2 from table2 where tracs='daraname2' AND kode='1-6'),
    W=(select W2 from table2 where tracs='daraname2' AND kode='1-6'),
    NW=(select NW2 from table2 where tracs='daraname2' AND kode='1-6')
WHERE tracsName='daraname2' AND tracsid='1-6'`

I'm having an error, and if you can give me the logic or the code it will be great.

Comment: Which sql? Mysql, sql server or?

Comment: for mysql i use mysql front,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general syntax for `mysql`:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 a 
JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.name1 = b.name2
SET a.n1 = b.n2
```

Here is example for `sql server`:

```
UPDATE a
SET n1 = b.n2    
FROM TABLE1 a 
JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.name1 = b.name2
```

Comment: thank you, it very nice, for now i have 2 server, back up is not possible, any idea how to use that code on 2 server mysql.? one on mylocal, and one is online.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
UPDATE  table1

SET     table1.N = table2.n
FROM table2 WHERE name2 = name1
```